# How does Wanda Maximoff know that Pietro is dead?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, scarlet-witch

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015), Pietro Maximoff is killed by a spray of gunfire while protecting Clint Barton. Wanda Maximoff (Pietro's sister), who is at the center of the city, immediately falls to her knees and screams as if she knew that Pietro was dead. Then (without seeing Pietro's body), she rips out Ultron's heart and says that that was what she felt like (presumably after Pietro's death).

However, the movie never shows her discovering he's dead directly after his death. **How does Wanda know Pietro died immediately following his death?**

Comment: Scarlet Witch is an incredibly powerful character, approaching omnipotence at times.  Keeping tabs on her brother seems like small potatoes for a sorceress of her power.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As we learn in *WandaVision*, Wanda had inherent magic powers from a young age — she likely used them unconsciously to prevent the Stark missile that landed in her family's apartment from exploding.

As she's Pietro's twin brother, he might share some of her magical abilities. Even if not, they were both experimented on with the Mind Stone, which might give them some further supernatural connection.

Either way, apparently some part of her abilities meant she was aware of his death, despite not being in his presence or [having access to cable news](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258579/how-did-mj-and-ned-know-the-fate-of-this-character). We haven't seen this ability manifested elsewhere, but Wanda doesn't have any living family members left.

We do, however, in the post-credits scene in *WandaVision*, see Wanda hearing the voices of the children she created in Westview. While this might be a hallucination or an illusion, it could be another example of Wanda having some telepathic ability.