# How did MJ and Ned know the fate of this character?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021),

> (Tom Holland's) Peter Parker's Aunt May is killed.

However, when

> Ned and MJ are talking to Andrew Garfield's Peter Parker, MJ says:
>  "We're kind of the only ones he has left." (or something like that)

How does MJ know that

> May is dead?

Or does she even know? Did I misread the situation? Later, Ned and MJ

> talk to Tom Holland's Peter Parker on the rooftop and offer condolences.

The only possible thing I can think of is

> a news anchor saying that there were several injuries and **at least one death**.

**How did MJ and Ned know that**

> **May was dead?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### They apparently learned about it via TV news coverage of the incident.

Ned and MJ are shown watching TV news coverage of the incident in a scene immediately following said incident, with both of them seemingly in a state of distress about what they're seeing and hearing.

And when they and the two other Spider-Men go and find their Peter on that rooftop, Tobey Maguire's Peter clearly indicates that he knew about May's death, which suggests they all knew about it.

> PETER (MAGUIRE): **Sorry... about May...**
>
> PETER (GARFIELD): Yeah. Sorry. I got some understanding of what it...
>
> PETER (HOLLAND): No, please don't tell me that you know what I'm going through.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021)</sub>